# SQL Linq Reservation Availability

Tags: c#, mysql, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, linq

I want to create a reservation system that has a function that checks availability of a room before booking. I am doing this in MVC asp net.

I am however having a problem with the SQL that is called to check the availability as My Reservation and RoomType tables have a many to many relationship.

My Tables and data model for this is as follows:

[image: Reservation_RoomType]
[image]

[image: DataModel]

[image]

So far I have managed to come up with the following on my own:

```
Select * from RoomTypes
 where id = 3 and not exists
    (select * from Reservation_RoomType 
    where ReservationId = 
        (select id from Reservations where Arrival <= '2017-05-18' and Depature >= '2017-05-20' ))
```

And in Linq

```
        var query = (from rooms in context.RoomTypes
                     where (rooms.Id == modelid) &&
                     !(context.Reservation_RoomTypes.Any(a => a.ReservationId ==
                               (from reservations in context.Reservations where (reservations.Arrival <= DateTime.Parse("2017-05-18"))
                                && (reservations.Depature => DateTime.Parse("2017-05-18"))) select *);
```

This should return no rooms due to my current seeding but still shows no rooms if I change the room Id to something else that should be available. SQL is not my strong point and I am positive my linq expression is wrongly formatted.Any and every help would be appreciated because im tearing my hair out!.

Comment: Which is the column you have used to check the availability of the room?

Comment: Do you want the availability of room type (single) or specific room (103)

Comment: Actually, as the db schema currently sits you cannot get actual room numbers that are available, just calculate how many rooms by type which  are available. Can the schemas be changed, or just the retrieval?

Comment: @MadMyche Yeah I have been thinking for a while the schema will have to be changed and thats fine. Im looking for the availability of a room type

Answer (score 0):

It would be much better to have a better understanding of what exactly you want from your results. I can only guess based on your current SQL.  I get hesitant when I see SQL that does not have a JOIN and has many SELECT statements (that does not mean it wrong at all it is just sometimes a red flag.)

Based on the information you have given I can only tell you what is wrong with your current  SQL.

Change

```
where ReservationId =
```

to

```
where ReservationId IN
```

In will evaluate all of the results.

If this does not work please give a better description of what you want from results what is your exact evaluation.

Comment: I agree with needing the clarity; I personally believe the db.schema needs to be revised if possible. All we really can do is see what rooms may be available as the _bridge_ table should be saving room number is addition to or replacing type.

Comment: @MadMyche 100% There, it confused me too, the one thing that got me is it seems that "ROOMTYPES" table is actually a "ROOMS" table — that naming choice that haunts every developer including the guy who wrote it. The SQL will always feel like you are doing something wrong.

Comment: @Eddie the outcome I am looking for is that an individual will be able to search for available rooms on their chosen dates and they can also choose specific room types like "Single" or "Double". Obviously if a room already has a reservation on these days then it will not be shown.